# Decoding a gzipped string in PHP

Tags: php, rest, gzip, guzzle, php-curl

I am trying to decode a gzipped body of a REST response (YouTrack-API) with PHP. Nothing seems to work:

- Automatic decoding from CURL does nothing
- Using Guzzle with headers set to accept encoding does nothing
- Simply putting the acquired string into gzdecode() does nothing

I have tried gzinflate, gzdecode and some wild combinations of them including stripping off bytes at the start and end, but without success. I am by no means an expert in compression, so I have no idea if there are even different formats a gzipped string can take, but any old 'online gzip service' can decode the string with no problem at all

Simple example:
This string:

```
H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJV8jPSVEozy/KSQEARAYhbw8AAAA=
```

should output:

```
Hello old world
```

Put into any online converter I could find, it works, put into any of the PHP functions: data error.
What is the deal with PHP and gzip not working at all? has it something to do with either the entire response being gzipped or just the contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gzipped string is base64 encoded, so you need to do:

```
echo gzdecode(base64_decode('H4sIAAAAAAAA//NIzcnJV8jPSVEozy/KSQEARAYhbw8AAAA='));
```

Comment: Thank you... But how would one know this? That API just states 'it's gzipped' and there is never any mention of it being base64 encoded. Can you just 'see' it from the way the string looks?

Comment: @RemizZ `=` is used as the padding at the end of base 64 encoded strings. If you see a string that consists of alphanumeric characters, `+` and `/`, with an equals sign at the end, it's a safe bet that it's base64 encoded.

Comment: @RemizZ what iainn said. Also, I've worked with gzipped APIs before ;)

Comment: Yes, you can just see it. Well-compressed data will be indistinguishable from random data, and so will have a flat distribution of all byte values from 0 to 255. If the string only has printable characters, i.e. less than 96 out of the possible 256, then you know that either it is not compressed, or that it is an encoding of the compressed binary data. The most common such encoding is Base-64, which happens to use one or two (or zero) terminating equal signs. So that would be the first one to try for that data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example:

Gzip Compressing in .NET/C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string s = "Hi!!";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        byte[] b2 = Compress(byteArray);

        Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(b2));
    }

    public static byte[] Compress(byte[] bytes) {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)) {
                gzipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] bytes) {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var decompressStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
                    decompressStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }
                return outputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code prints the base64 encoded compressed string which is `H4sIAAAAAAAEAPPIVFQEANxaFPgEAAAA` for the `Hi!!` input.

Now - here's the code for decompressing in PHP:

```
echo gzdecode(base64_decode('H4sIAAAAAAAEAPPIVFQEANxaFPgEAAAA'));
```